# How to call function with key value pair written in return block?

Tags: javascript, function

Inspired from angular service method declaration, I am using plain javascript file and write function in the below way (I don't know what this approach is called)

#### test.js

```
var MyService = function() {
        var base;

        var service = {
            init: function (formdata) {
                base.name = formdata.name;
                console.log('calling init');
            },
            other: function () {
               console.log('caling other');
            }
        }
        return service;
}
```

Now in HTML I want to call it like `MyService.init(formdata);`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scratchpad</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script>
    var formdata = {};
    function generateData() {
        var form = document.getElementById('Myform');
        formdata.name = 'Alpha';
        console.log(formdata);
        MyService.init(formdata);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Myform" role="form" method="post">
  <button type="button" onclick="generateData()">Generate Data</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but it produces the following error

**uncaught ReferenceError: MyService is not defined**

Can't we achieve this way in plain javascript?

Comment: Usie prototype. I believe that is what you looking for

Comment: `MyService` is a function.

Comment: @AdamAzad how to use prototype? Please explain or suggest any link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use prototype. This is intended for creating SDK designs. If you encounter any JavaScript SDK, you will see a similar pattern. That doesn't mean you can't use, though, I personally use it in all my projects.

You should enclose `MyService` in a private scope to avoid conflict with other namespaces, and return only `MyService`.

```
(function(){

    // move all variables to here
    var base;

    var _service = function(){
       // this is the constructor function, the initial functions can be run from here
    }


    _service.prototype = {

            init: function (formdata) {
                base.name = formdata.name;
                console.log('calling init');
            },
            other: function () {
               console.log('caling other');
            }
    }

    // invoke _service as myService in global scope
    window.MyService = new _service();

})();
```

Now you can access all function of MyService with

```
MyService.init({name:'James'}); // calling init
MyService.other(); // caling other
```

Comment: Is there no need of `return _service`?

Comment: @pro.mean, no because `MyService` being returned to window scope. Try that code above, and then type `MyService` in console, and you will see `_service`

Comment: this is really cool. but what if I want to add init() method body  in constructor method  `var_service = function (formdata)` how do I send formdata into the constructor?

Comment: Unfortunately, that would not be possible with this kind of design, because the function is invoked. That is why we have `init` to initialize the service as an constructor.

Comment: okay. than when we can do in constructor method? can we write variable inside constructor which can be use in internal methods? can `var base`  initialised  inside constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the internal variable in the constructor. But all variables must be defined in the scope. For example, if the page has predefined variable(s), the constructor can catch those, and update its variables accordingly
.

Answer (score 4):

`MyService` is a function not an object which has properties, you need to invoke as

```
MyService().init(formdata);
```

also base is undefined, so it has to be initialized as

```
var base = {};
```

Complete example

```
var MyService = function() {
        var base = {};
        var service = {
            init: function (formdata) {
                base.name = formdata.name;
                console.log('calling init');
            },
            other: function () {
               console.log('caling other');
            }
        }
        return service;
}


MyService().init({name:"2"}) ; //outputs 'calling init'
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. But in this way I have to call `Myservice().AnyMethod` each time. any other alternative so that I must call `AnyMethod() ` without instantiate `MyService()` on each method invoke

Comment: you can cache the response of `MyService()` into a variable and then use that variable to invoke the `init` method. `var obj = MyService(); obj.init();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 function MyService() {
  this.base = "some thing";
  }

  MyService.prototype.init = function(formdata) {

   console.log('calling init =>'+this.base);
  }

 MyService.prototype.other = function(formdata) {

 console.log('caling other');
  }

var myser = new MyService();
myser.init(1);
 myser.other();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function generateVPC() {
        var form = document.getElementById('Myform');
        formdata.name = 'Alpha';
        console.log(formdata);
        var myservice = new MyService();
        myservice.init(formdata);
      }
```

and base is also giving error so define base as

```
var base = {};
```